# I have build an simple app using ionic with angular ? How do i generate apk file with capacitor without using android studio?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to generate an apk file in ionic. is it possible to generate apk file without using android studio ? how can i do that ?
How do i do that without android studio but using only capacitor?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Android Studio.

https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/building-your-app#android

> Currently, Android relies on Android Studio (or, optionally, the Android CLI tools) to build the app

Further information on how to setup and compile:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/android